# How much should we value karma of users

Tags: discussion

In the last days I repeatedly saw responses to critic,
trying to degrade the critics by pointing out to low karma or activity.

Is providing critic not a valuable kind of participation?

Answer (score 2):

> Is providing critic not a valuable kind of participation?

I my mind heck yeah it is 100% valuable participation.

The main problems with critic is that everyone takes it differently and it is very hard to tell the tone of someone via 100 characters or so.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem on the discussion on twitter was kind of:

We are giving our best here, but we are overwhelmed by all the newbie questions, which could easily be answered by google.

So we do our best here and instead of helping us, you criticize us. Which I think is correct from the content but a few of us, including me, take it personally and this feels unfair.

But this is our problem not yours.